# How to make git push only update the commited files on the server?

Tags: git, github

I am using Git Version Control in cpanel. It has update from remote option it updates the changes from my bitbucket repo.
I have db/config.php file first time I cloned the repo in my cpanel it fetched everything from my repo including the db/config.php file.
I had to change my db/config.php file only once the first time. I updated it with the servers database details.

Now every time I push the changes from my local computer to bitbucket. I can go to cpanel's git version control and update from remote. https://i.stack.imgur.com/egDZD.png

I have another server and this one doesnt have cpanel so I have to do things differently here
https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000732471-Pushing-your-local-Git-repository-to-a-DreamHost-server-Windows

Its the same project on a different server.
After I have made changes in my local system. I just use the command `git push dreamhost main`

My branches:
 `git branch -a`

Output-

```
* main
  remotes/dreamhost/main
```

As you can see dreamhost is the remote branch here.

Now the issue is that I edited the config file on the dreamhost server with the server's database details.
I went back to the project on my local system and made a few changes and committed them in the main branch.
I then used `git push dreamhost main` to update the local changes to my server and it added my new changes which was fine but It also overwrote the db/config.php file which I didnt touch. I had only updated that file in the server. It is normal for it to get overwritten with every git push ? How to avoid it and only update the committed changes?

On this server I have example.com.git directory and from there the changes are updated automatically to my website using this hook whenever there is a push
https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000684492-Using-Git-for-web-development

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/username/example.com git checkout -f main
```

I was expecting that git push only pushes the committed changes to the server. It seems that it is overwriting the files that I edit on the server because it wants it to be the same? In cpanel it works fine only the committed changes are updated.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have remote server that automatically checks out the `main` branch of your repo. You edited file A in the remote server source tree (without committing changes, correct?). Later, you edited file B in your local repo, commited that change to master, and pushed `main` to the remote repository. Now you are wondering where the changes to file A went after the remote server checked-out out the tip of `main`?

Comment: I recommend that you read about other strategies for configuration that varies between environments. Often we use environment variables or files that aren't committed to version control for this kind of configuration.

Comment: Git will push exactly what you commit. Did you commit changes to db/config.php? That said, if you have to maintain different configurations in difference environments with a common code-base, [put that info in environment variables](https://www.12factor.net/config).

Comment: Do note that the -f (for `--force`) in `GIT_WORK_TREE=... git checkout -f main` means "please obliterate the working tree to completely match the target revision; ignore and throw away any local changes". If didn't pass `-f`, you would have gotten an error to the local changes to `db/config.php`.

Comment: @Brian61354270 Yes I edited file A in the server which is the config file lets say. Now in the local repo i edited another file B which is totally different. I committed the changes and pushed it to remote server the file b got updated but the File A also got overwritten. File A had config details of the server while file A in my local computer has config details of localhost server. This doesnt happen on cpanel but it happens with git push on this server. Is this normal

Comment: You probably want to _not_ track that config file if you are expecting it to have local modifications; or e.g. change it to source the relevant settings from the environment. Here’s a reference https://www.12factor.net/config

Comment: Yes, it is very normal. Git works with entire source trees at a time. A commit identities the exact state of a complete source tree. If you want to merge changes made to different checkouts, you'd need commit both sets of changes to the repo make a [merge](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging).

Comment: Please address comments by incorporating the missing info into the question.